# Shorter format of match query

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "tokyo apple",
            "operator" : "AND"
        }
    }
}
```

The above one doesn't work. I thought the [shorter format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-short-ex) works for this also. But it didn't.

Any reasons? Or only with `query` field it works?

I am getting `"reason": "[match] query doesn't support multiple fields, found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is almost correct.
Longer:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "tokyo apple",
        "operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Shorter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "tokyo apple"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So please correct my understanding. Only operator can be used in longer format. Shorter format useful only just for query terms without extra query options.